# WinError 6: The handle is invalid from python check_output spawn in Electron app

Tags: python, electron, pyinstaller

I have an Electron app `xxx.exe` which is spawning an executable created from PyInstaller `yyy.exe`. In, `yyy.exe`, I am finally trying to launch a `git` cmd via `subprocess.check_output()`.
Sadly, the call to `check_output()` throws `[WinError 6] The handle is invalid`.

If `yyy.exe` is directly launched on the command line, everything is running fine.
The issue is only happening on Windows. My assumption is that there are some checks on `stdin` that trigger the exception because running through an Electron app doesn't provide any Stdin.

Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks so much for the alternative, I did not get further along this path after trying `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` which failed...

Comment: @eryksun please put your answer so you can get the reward! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, `subprocess.Popen` tries to duplicate non-zero standard handles and fails if they're invalid. You can redirect `stdin` and `stderr` to NUL. For example:

```
import os

try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL
except ImportError:
    DEVNULL = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)

output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

Comment: Plase make sure that you close the file handler DEVNULL after opening.

Comment: @AstitvaSrivastava, I intended for the `DEVNULL` file descriptor to be left open and reused for the life of a Python 2 process. If this is being used in a library, then it might be better to close it via `if not hasattr(subprocess, "DEVNULL"): os.close(DEVNULL)`, but not necessarily since consuming a single file descriptor is not a practical problem, especially if it's documented.

Comment: I did you use your method in a multithreaded application where a polling (discovery of disks) is done by executing a command using check_output. After certain discoveries, I was getting "Too Many Files Open" error. @eryksun

Comment: @AstitvaSrivastava, again, I intended for `DEVNULL` to be a global constant at module level in Python 2. I didn't write a function that would open `os.devnull` every time it's called. If you're doing that, then the file descriptor needs to be closed, and call `check_output` in a try-finally that guarantees `os.close` is called in the `finally` block.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood it. Thanks. @eryksun

Comment: NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined

Comment: @AlexZab, `cmd` is the argument list or command-line string that you're trying to execute. The value is up to you.

Comment: I know) I have almost the same problem, and can not resolve it( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766452/oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid-in-pysimplegui-while-using-w-in