# subprocess seems not working in pyinstaller exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

My program in `tkinter` is working well when I am running it using `PyCharm`, 
when I am creating `.exe` file using pyinstaller,
`pyinstaller -i"icon.ico" -w -F script.py`
I have no errors.
I am pasting `script.exe` in same folder as my `script.py`, and after running it I think in step where `subprocess` is, it is not answering, because I have`print` before subprocess line and its working.

Anyone know why?

This is the line with subprocess:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 s = subprocess.Popen([EXE,files,'command'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**EDIT:**

same problem with:

```
s = subprocess.check_output([EXE,files,'command'],shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Using `subprocess.Popen()` within a pyinstaller-generated binary requires some modifications. Check [**this recipe**](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess) both as an example and an explanation of what's going on.

Comment: @zwer thanks, but  when i am using `close_fds=True` i am receiving this error: `raise ValueError("close_fds is not supported on Windows "
ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved by not using `-w` command for generating exe file from .py script.

Answer (score 14):

You can compile your code in -w mode or --windowed, but then you have to assign stdin and stderr as well.

So change:

```
s = subprocess.Popen([EXE,files,'command'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

to:

```
s = subprocess.Popen([EXE,files,'command'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: @DaanWittenburg I tried this with the "systeminfo" command, button my python program will just freeze. Any idea why this is? This only happens when I use the --noconsole command. Without it, it runs fine. I also see a popup, but it doesn't really do anything. It closes after a while, but nothing gets written to my file.

Comment: This answer worked for me, even if using the `-w` or `--noconsole` options.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function to get the command's output instead. Works with -F and -w option:

```
import subprocess
def popen(cmd: str) -> str:
    """For pyinstaller -w"""
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,startupinfo=startupinfo, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    return decode_utf8_fixed(process.stdout.read())
```

Comment: I didn’t know that :o On Linux, one must use the equivalent module „fctnl“... I‘m pretty sure that can do what startupinfo can do on windows. And there are much mode threads regarding flags with fctnl :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error
`[WinError 6] The handle is invalid`
when running the line

```
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

This solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43606682/12668094

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with some of the solutions from this and other threads, found another option, Windows-specific, but works with or without pyinstaller (windowed or console):

- if you don't care about capturing the output of the process and want to run it in a separate console window, allowing the user to interact with it, and wait until it finishes, you can do this:

  ```
    import subprocess
    def popen(cmd):
        args = {'stdin' : subprocess.PIPE,
                'stderr': subprocess.PIPE,
                'stdout': subprocess.PIPE,
                'env'   : os.environ}
        process = subprocess.Popen(['start','cmd','/C'] + cmd, close_fds=True, shell=True, **args)
        return process

    def run_subproc(args):
        '''helper method to run a subprocess in a separate console window'''
        p = popen(args)
        output, err = p.communicate() # <- this is the key line to wait for process completion
        status = p.wait()             # <- doesn't actually wait if 'start' used

    if __name__=='__main__':
        run_subproc(['program.exe','arg1','arg2'])
  ```