# Why is this subprocess.check_output line crashing my script?

Tags: python, split, subprocess, pyinstaller, strsplit

I have a script that works fine when in a .pyw, but when converted to an .exe, (EDIT: actually, when I use pyinstaller with the arguments `-w` or `--windowed` or `--noconsole` it doesn't work, but without them it works) I've found that this one single line seems to crash the program:

```
firstplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-list"], shell=True ).split('\n')[3]
```

Does anybody have any idea why? If I comment it out the program doesn't crash. I have two other very similar lines.

EDIT:

Maybe it'd be a good idea to put the script here...

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
# os.system('cls')
import psutil
import subprocess

loop = 1

while loop == (1):

    CPUload = (psutil.cpu_percent(interval=4))      # CPU load
    RAMload = (psutil.virtual_memory().percent)     # RAM load

    # os.system('cls')

    print("CPU Load: ", end="")         # Display CPU Load:
    print(CPUload, "%")                 # Display CPUload
    print("RAM Load: ", end="")         # Display CPU Load:
    print(str(RAMload) + " %")          # Display RAMload

    firstplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-list"], shell=True ).split('\n')[3]      # Selects a line
    secondplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-list"], shell=True ).split('\n')[4]
    thirdplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-list"], shell=True ).split('\n')[5]

    firstplanID = ((firstplan.split(": "))[1].split("  (")[0])      # Extract XplanID from Xplan
    secondplanID = ((secondplan.split(": "))[1].split("  (")[0])
    thirdplanID = ((thirdplan.split(": "))[1].split("  (")[0])

    activeplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/getactivescheme"])      # Find the currently active plan
    activeplanNAME = ((activeplan.split("("))[1].split(")")[0])     # Extract activeplanNAME from activeplan

    firstplanNAME = ((firstplan.split("("))[1].split(")")[0])       # Extract XplanNAME from Xplan
    secondplanNAME = ((secondplan.split("("))[1].split(")")[0])
    thirdplanNAME = ((thirdplan.split("("))[1].split(")")[0])


    if "High performance" in firstplanNAME:         # Identify which plan is High performance
        HighPerformance = firstplanNAME
        HighPerformanceID = firstplanID

    if "High performance" in secondplanNAME:
        HighPerformance = secondplanNAME
        HighPerformanceID = secondplanID

    if "High performance" in thirdplanNAME:
        HighPerformance = thirdplanNAME
        HighPerformanceID = thirdplanID

    if "Power saver" in firstplanNAME:              # Identify which plan is Power saver
        PowerSaver = firstplanNAME
        PowerSaverID = firstplanID

    if "Power saver" in secondplanNAME:
        PowerSaver = secondplanNAME
        PowerSaverID = secondplanID

    if "Power saver" in thirdplanNAME:
        PowerSaver = thirdplanNAME  
        PowerSaverID = thirdplanID


    if activeplanNAME == PowerSaver:            # Checks current plan name
        print("Active plan: Power saver")
    else:
        if activeplanNAME == HighPerformance:
            print("Active plan: High Performance")
        else: 
            subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", HighPerformanceID])          


    if CPUload < 44:    
        if RAMload > 90:
            if activeplanNAME == PowerSaver:
                subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", HighPerformanceID])
                print("Switching to High Performance by RAM load...")       

    if CPUload < 44:    
        if RAMload < 90:
            if activeplanNAME == HighPerformance:
                subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", PowerSaverID])
                print("Switching to Power saver...")                    

    if CPUload > 55:
        if activeplanNAME == PowerSaver:
            subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", HighPerformanceID])
            print("Switching to High Performance...")
```

The troubled lines are lines 21-23.

For further info, scroll down to comments and answers.

Comment: Passing the commands as a list with `shell=True` apparently happens to work on some platforms, but is really not the right thing.  Take out `shell=True`.  (I don't think this will solve your problem, though.)

Comment: The indentation in the script you shared is clearly wrong (some or all of the lines after the `while` loop near the beginning should be indented).  Please take care to post valid code; indentation is significant with Python in particular. See also [Markdown help](/editing-help).

Comment: @tripleee What do you mean not really the right thing? Also yeah I took out the `shell=True` before and it still didn't work. Also I will fix the indentation, it is indented in my script but I forgot to indent on the site.

Comment: The `subprocess` documentation has the details. If you use `shell=True` you should pass in a string for the shell to parse; with `shell=False` (or no `shell=True`) you need to pass in a list of parsed tokens.

Comment: @tripleee - I'm sorry I'm new to Python, should I just take out the `shell=True` entirely to make it `firstplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "-list"]).split('\n')[3]`? Or should I change it to false?

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit so change to `shell=False` although technically taking it out will do the same thing.

Comment: Calling a shell three times to get three lines of output from the same command is also pretty wasteful. Just do `pcfg = subprocess.check_output(['powercfg', '-list']).split('\n')` and then `first = pcfg[3]`,  `second = pcfg[4]` etc.

Comment: Does the command really accept `-list` as an option and even if it does, wouldn't it be better to use `/list` for consistency? (Assuming the command is consistent in the first place. This is apparently Windows, after all...)

Comment: @tripleee - You're right about the consistency. I must have missed that! Thank you so much for helping me with this. I used the pcfg value like this: `pcfg = subprocess.check_output(['powercfg', '/list']).split('\n') and (then (firstplan = pcfg[3], secondplan = pcfg[4], thirdplan = pcfg[5]))` and it tells me after `firstplan` that it is invalid syntax.

Comment: Hold on I realized now that was dumb. I now have `pcfg = subprocess.check_output(['powercfg', '/list']).split('\n')`
 `firstplan = pcfg[3], secondplan = pcfg[4], thirdplan = pcfg[5]` and it says that there are too many values to unpack. I think it has something to do with how doing `print(pcfg)` gives the values is separate strings instead of separate lines like how it was before.

Comment: You need the assignments on separate lines. Alternatively, Python allows you to put semicolons between statements, but this is generally avoided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177465/discussion-between-jangles-and-tripleee).

Comment: Just a stylistic point to make your code less cluttered, instead of 3x3 variables `firstplan, firstplanID, firstplanNAME...` why not just have arrays `plan[0:2], plan_id[0:2], plan_name[0:2]` or even declare a class whose __init__() takes the raw output from `subprocess.check_output` and extracts `id` and `name` string fields. (CodeReview.SE site is better for soliciting general comments like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but here is a refactoring which addresses the problems which were pointed out in comments, as well as some other issues with your code.

- Don't use a loop variable. (It was unused anyway.)
- Don't run the same subprocess three times.
- Avoid the gratuitous `shell=True`
- Prefer `/list` over `-list` for consistency and possibly correctness.

I have removed your comments and inlined comments of mine explaining what exactly was changed.

```
# Only necessary in Python 2, you really should be using Python 3 now
#from __future__ import print_function
# Only used in os.system('cls') which was commented out (for good reasons I presume)
#import os
import psutil
import subprocess
from time import sleep # see below

# Simply loop forever; break when done
while True:
    # Remove gratuitous parentheses
    CPUload = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=4)
    RAMload = psutil.virtual_memory().percent

    # Use .format() to inline a string
    print("CPU Load: {}%".format(CPUload)))
    print("RAM Load: {}%".format(RAMload))

    # Only run subprocess once; use /list pro -list; don't use shell=True
    pcfg = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/list"], shell=False).split('\n')
    # Additional refactoring below ########
    firstplan = pcfg[3]
    secondplan = pcfg[4]
    thirdplan = pcfg[5]

    # Get rid of wacky parentheses    
    firstplanID = firstplan.split(": ")[1].split("  (")[0]
    secondplanID = secondplan.split(": ")[1].split("  (")[0]
    thirdplanID = thirdplan.split(": ")[1].split("  (")[0]

    activeplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/getactivescheme"])
    # Get rid of wacky parentheses
    activeplanNAME = activeplan.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]    
    firstplanNAME = firstplan.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
    secondplanNAME = secondplan.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
    thirdplanNAME = thirdplan.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]

    if "High performance" in firstplanNAME:
        HighPerformance = firstplanNAME
        HighPerformanceID = firstplanID

    if "High performance" in secondplanNAME:
        HighPerformance = secondplanNAME
        HighPerformanceID = secondplanID

    if "High performance" in thirdplanNAME:
        HighPerformance = thirdplanNAME
        HighPerformanceID = thirdplanID

    if "Power saver" in firstplanNAME:
        PowerSaver = firstplanNAME
        PowerSaverID = firstplanID

    if "Power saver" in secondplanNAME:
        PowerSaver = secondplanNAME
        PowerSaverID = secondplanID

    if "Power saver" in thirdplanNAME:
        PowerSaver = thirdplanNAME  
        PowerSaverID = thirdplanID

    # Additional refactoring ends    

    if activeplanNAME == PowerSaver:
        print("Active plan: Power saver")
    # prefer if / elif / else over nested if
    elif activeplanNAME == HighPerformance:
        print("Active plan: High Performance")
    else:
        # What's this supposed to do? You are capturing, then discarding the output.
        # Perhaps you are looking for subprocess.check_call()?
        subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", HighPerformanceID])          

    if CPUload < 44:    
        # Combine conditions rather than nesting conditionals
        if RAMload > 90 and activeplanNAME == PowerSaver:
            # subprocess.check_call() here too?
            subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", HighPerformanceID])
            print("Switching to High Performance by RAM load...")       

        # Don't check if CPUload < 44: again
        # Instead, just stay within this indented block
        # Combine conditions
        elif RAMload < 90 and activeplanNAME == HighPerformance:
            # subprocess.check_call() here too?
            subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", PowerSaverID])
            print("Switching to Power saver...")                    

        # What if RAMload == 90?

    # Combine conditions
    if CPUload > 55 and activeplanNAME == PowerSaver:
        # subprocess.check_call() here too?
        subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/s", HighPerformanceID])
        print("Switching to High Performance...")

    # Maybe sleep between iterations?
    #sleep(1)
```

The script currently runs a rather tight loop, you might want to uncomment the last line.

There is still a lot of repetitive code.  You might want to consider further refactoring to collect the three plans into an array where each object is a dict with member names identifying different properties you have extracted.

```
    # Additional refactoring below ########
    activeplan = subprocess.check_output(["powercfg", "/getactivescheme"])
    activeplanNAME = activeplan.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]    

    plan = []
    for idx in range(3):
        raw = pcfg[3+idx]
        thisplan = {'raw': raw}
        thisplan['id'] = raw.split(": ")[1].split("  (")[0]
        thisplan['name'] = raw.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]

        if "High performance" in thisplan['name']:
            HighPerformance = thisplan['name']
            HighPerformanceID = thisplan['id']    

        if "Power saver" in thisplan['name']:
            PowerSaver = thisplan['name']
            PowerSaverID = thisplan['id']

        plan[idx] = thisplan
```

Now you could actually change the `HighPerformance` and `PowerSaver` variables to just remember the `idx` and then if you want to, you can pull out the name from the list of dicts with `plan[PowerSaverIdx]['name']` and ID with `plan[PowerSaverIdx]['id']`.

Comment: So I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706087/8142044 and that fixed the script crashing when in a `--noconsole` mode and after I took out `stdout-subprocess.PIPE`. I put this for every `subprocess.check_output`. However, the program will flash a command prompt every couple seconds which defeats the purpose of a background running process.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that. My solution was to abandon Windows entirely and it was one of the best decisions I've made.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help though! I will start a new question. Also what OS do you use?

Comment: Blanket recommendations are problematic but for what I do, I prefer Debian Linux.