# Is there a way to get a list of processus with PyInstaller windowed?

Tags: python, process, pyinstaller, windowed

I'm trying to test if a browser is open on a python program converted to an `exe` with `pyinstaller`, Is there a way to test this without displaying a window and converting it to an `exe`?

I tried subprocess but it creates an error with the windowed mode of pyinstaller and I can't import `psutil` into `pyinstaller ("can't import psutil" error)`

The code I use with `subprocess`:

`enter code here`subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)

The program does not start and an error message appears: "Failed to execute script"
A similar error posted here: [subprocess seems not working in pyinstaller exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463238/subprocess-seems-not-working-in-pyinstaller-exe-file/51706087#51706087)

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Can you add more code? It is hard to grasp the problem you are dealing with, without code snippet and platform specific details

Comment: Of course:
Configuration :
Windows-10-10.0.0.17134-SP0
Python 3.7.4
PyInstaller: 3.4

For the code :
It is a timer that decreases only if a browser is open :

        global timer;
        e=str(subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True));
        if "chrome.exe" in e or 'firefox.exe' in e or 'iexplore.exe' in e: ;
            timer-=1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check whether a process running or not you can use [`psutil.process_iter`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.process_iter) but as Pyinstaller can't quite resolve the `psutil` module you need to use [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag to add the whole Lib folder to your output executable:

```
import psutil
process_to_find = "chrome.exe"
process_list = [p.name() for p in list(psutil.process_iter())]
if process_to_find in process_list:
   # do whatever you want
   print("Process found!")
```

Next use below command to generate your executable (you can also use `-w` flag as well):

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "<python_path>\Lib\site-packages\psutil;./psutil" script.py
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!
P.S. : I had another problem with psutil, it was in a second python installation, if other people can't import it, check that it is in the LIB folder of the python you are using. Otherwise just copy it from the other python.