# How to set a dictionary based off of subprocess.check_output

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ffmpeg, subprocess, ffprobe

This is a confusing question, however I will try to make it as clear as possible.
Currently when I build my app, if I run it via the .py file it works perfectly. However, once I compile it some parts of my app aren't functioning, specifically this code here.

```
def ffprobe_run():
global output
global acodec_choices
run = subprocess.check_output("ffprobe " + videoinputquoted + " " + ffprobecommand, universal_newlines=True)
print(run)
if run[-2] == '3':
    acodec_choices = {"One": "1",
                      "Two": "2",
                      "Three": "3"}
elif run[-2] == '2':
    acodec_choices = {"One": "1",
                      "Two": "2",}
elif run[-2] == '1':
    acodec_choices = {"One": "1",}
print(acodec_choices.values())
```

I am able to get the results I want with this command. Currently that's using FFPROBE to check for the amount of audio tracks there is in a file. It returns values like so

```
1
2
3
```

If there is 3 tracks. Or

```
1 
2
```

If it's two tracks. I use the command[-2]
which will give me the result of '2'

So I'm taking that result and defining a dictionary to automatically populate/change an OptionMenu

It defines this in my main app

```
 # Audio Stream Selection
    acodec_stream = StringVar(audio_window)
    if ffprobeinfo[-2] == '1':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '2':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '3':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '4':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '5':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3",
                                 'Track 5': "-map 0:a:4"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '6':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3",
                                 'Track 5': "-map 0:a:4",
                                 'Track 6': "-map 0:a:5"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '7':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3",
                                 'Track 5': "-map 0:a:4",
                                 'Track 6': "-map 0:a:5",
                                 'Track 7': "-map 0:a:6"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '8':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3",
                                 'Track 5': "-map 0:a:4",
                                 'Track 6': "-map 0:a:5",
                                 'Track 7': "-map 0:a:6",
                                 'Track 8': "-map 0:a:7"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '9':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3",
                                 'Track 5': "-map 0:a:4",
                                 'Track 6': "-map 0:a:5",
                                 'Track 7': "-map 0:a:6",
                                 'Track 8': "-map 0:a:7",
                                 'Track 9': "-map 0:a:8"}
    elif ffprobeinfo[-2] == '10':
        acodec_stream_choices = {'Track 1': "-map 0:a:0",
                                 'Track 2': "-map 0:a:1",
                                 'Track 3': "-map 0:a:2",
                                 'Track 4': "-map 0:a:3",
                                 'Track 5': "-map 0:a:4",
                                 'Track 6': "-map 0:a:5",
                                 'Track 7': "-map 0:a:6",
                                 'Track 8': "-map 0:a:7",
                                 'Track 9': "-map 0:a:8",
                                 'Track 10': "-map 0:a:9"}
    acodec_stream.set('Track 1')  # set the default option
    acodec_stream_label = Label(audio_window, text="Track :")
    acodec_stream_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    acodec_stream_menu = OptionMenu(audio_window, acodec_stream, *acodec_stream_choices.keys())
    acodec_stream_menu.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

This is all working great, If I am running the app via the .py file. Once I compile it's missing the entire defined dictionary selection.

This is what it's supposed to look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPSRD.png)

However, this is what it looks like with the code above. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJCfS.png)

If I define the dictionary myself, it works fine. However, then I can't automatically input the correct amount of available audio tracks.

I hope this isn't too much code. I'm very new at this.

EDIT:

If I compile via pyinstaller and remove the -w flag, the program runs correctly, shows the tracks.

I'm assuming I'm not using subprocess/calling something correctly. The program I don't think is calling to FFPROBE when it doesn't have a console, vs calling it and getting the value when it has it's own console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post was the answer. Specifically the 2nd post, was exactly what I needed.

[subprocess seems not working in pyinstaller exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463238/subprocess-seems-not-working-in-pyinstaller-exe-file)

The program is working perfectly now.