# How do I use subprocess.run with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have a script that uses `subprocess.run` in this manner:

```
from subprocess import run
p1 = run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

Then I run:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole myscript.py
```

This does create an executable file but it seems that the script freezes for some reason.
What should I do so that the script does not freeze?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subprocess seems not working in pyinstaller exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463238/subprocess-seems-not-working-in-pyinstaller-exe-file)

Comment: Could you provide the command value?

Answer (score 1):

Is it freezing whilst the executable is being made, or after? If it is freezing during the process, it is because `subprocess.run` will wait for the process to end (in your case, the process is making the executable). This means that any subsequent code will not be run until the executable is made.

Comment: even after I set the command to something like 'dir', it doesn't work

Comment: @Vedant Jumle When you say that it freezes, is there any code after what you have provided that is never run after the executable is made, or are you on about the program temporarily freezing whilst making the executable?