# os.system doesn't work after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: python, command, pyinstaller, eel

I am trying to get the duration of an online video
using ffprobe

My program runs perfectly when I run it normally,
however when I try to use pyinstaller to compile the script to an exe
I click it and
the `os.system('ffprobe -i "{ URL Here}" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"' > temp.txt')` doesn't seem to output anything to the file , when running the non-comiled script it works perfectly and does what is supposed to do

```
import time
import re
import os, sys,tempfile
import eel
import ffmpy
import win32gui
import subprocess

eel.init('interface') # start the GUI

@eel.expose
def getDuration(url):
    duration = readcmd('ffprobe -i "{}" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"'.format(url))
    # duration = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', url, '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0")])
    return duration.rstrip()

def readcmd(cmd):
    os.system(cmd + " > temp.txt")
    data = ""
    with open('temp.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        file.close()
    os.remove('temp.txt')
    return data

eel.start('index.html', size=(1124, 768), mode = 'chrome') # Maybe I will implment Browser Fallback in the future
```

I have looked here [subprocess seems not working in pyinstaller exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463238/subprocess-seems-not-working-in-pyinstaller-exe-file)
I have tried running pyinstaller with
 `-w` and without `-noconsole`
here is how I compile :
`python -m eel main.py interface --noconsole --add-binary "./ffmpeg.exe;./" --add-binary "./ffprobe.exe;./"`

I am using `eel` for gui

Comment: Your first code snippet is not valid Python.

Comment: Well , yes I omiited the Imports , I will add them thanks @KlausD.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what you mean I see it as complete, can you please elaborate ?? os.system(cmd + " > temp.txt") @KlausD.

Comment: Oh Sorry I didn't see that at first, I understand now Thanks @KlausD.

Comment: `os.system` works fine with `pyinstaller`, could you compile the exe in the console mode, i.e., without the `--noconsole` flag, to see the errors (if any) that occur while your program is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well It turns out that I am kinda stupid, after wasting 2 days of my life to figure it out.

The problem is that when I was building with pyinstaller i didn't include the dll files for 
ffmpeg which was causing it to fail. :) please don't laugh

to solve the problem I am adding `--add-data` for every dll when using pyinstaller and it is now solved. or you can manually copy the dll files to the dist folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auto-py-to-exe`

Install it using `pip install auto-py-to-exe` and run it by typing `auto-py-to-exe` in cmd.

Note that this generates a folder, not a single `.exe` as far as I know. For more info go to https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi

Comment: This is simply a GUI for pyinstaller, while I will start using that thank you for help, that still doesn't answer my question. I tried to compile with it but still, the same problem occurs

Comment: `auto-py-to-exe` uses `pyinstaller`, it just provides an easy GUI to work with. It has no advantages over using `pyinstaller` directly.