# Can't get pyinstaller to work with --onefile and --noconsole

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a gui program which I use to process scanned pdfs and look for pages with QR codes, which tell the program where to split the pdf up into multiple files. My program is essentially a list of functions which call each other one after another as each step is completed.

Where I'm having trouble is when I try to compile it into an exe with pyinstaller. My program works fine as a python file, and also functions normally when I specify the --noconsole and the --onefile option. What I can not get to work is when I use both. For some reason, trying to get a working program with both --onefile and --noconsole inevitably fails. It boots up fine, but always fails at the same part. Here is the code from the section where it fails:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import shutil
import pathlib
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol
from json import loads
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import fitz
import win32com.client
import win32timezone
import os
import os.path
from os import path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sys import exit
import tempfile

def scan_reader(filepath):
    '''takes a filepath pointing to a pdf file and returns the number of pages, as well as any QR data that could be pulled from the pages'''

    # Converts the pdf into a list of images, one for each page
    images = convert_from_path(filepath, size = (500, None), dpi = 300, poppler_path = 'bin', grayscale=True)
    # For each page image: searches page for QR, and if qr is found it adds it to the page_qr_data dictionary in the format page number:qr data
    page_qr_data = {}
    for idx, image in enumerate(images):
        # Decode the QR image
        detectedBarcodes = decode(image, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])       
        # If not detected then continue to the next page
        if not detectedBarcodes:
            continue
        else:
            # If QR detected, adds the page number to page_qr_data as a key and makes a list of the qr data for the value
            page_qr_data[idx] = []
            for barcode in detectedBarcodes:
                page_qr_data[idx].append(barcode.data)

    return len(images), page_qr_data

def scan_reader_window():
    '''Presents the user with a list of files that have been pulled and asks them to select which ones they'd like to import'''
    files = os.listdir(temp_pdf_dir)
    receivers_dict = {}
    page_lengths = {}
    i = 0
    for file in files:
        if sg.one_line_progress_meter('Processing files...', i+1, len(files), f'(Step 2 of 2) Processing files...\n{file}', key = 'file_processor', orientation = 'horizontal'):
            filepath = f'{temp_pdf_dir}/{file}'
            page_lengths[file], raw_scan_data = scan_reader(filepath)
            for key, value in raw_scan_data.copy().items():
                if len(value) > 1:
                    del raw_scan_data[key]
                raw_scan_data[key] = value[0]
    
            for key, value in raw_scan_data.copy().items():
                try:
                    raw_scan_data[key] = loads(value)
                except:
                    del raw_scan_data[key]
    
            for key, value in raw_scan_data.copy().items():
                if 'DB_FILENAME: ' not in value:
                    del raw_scan_data[key]
                else:
                    raw_scan_data[key] = value[20:]
            receivers_dict[file] = raw_scan_data
            i += 1
        elif i == len(files)-1:
            filepath = f'{temp_pdf_dir}/{file}'
            page_lengths[file], raw_scan_data = scan_reader(filepath)
            for key, value in raw_scan_data.copy().items():
                if len(value) > 1:
                    del raw_scan_data[key]
                raw_scan_data[key] = value[0]
    
            for key, value in raw_scan_data.copy().items():
                try:
                    raw_scan_data[key] = loads(value)
                except:
                    del raw_scan_data[key]
    
            for key, value in raw_scan_data.copy().items():
                if 'DB_FILENAME: ' not in value:
                    del raw_scan_data[key]
                else:
                    raw_scan_data[key] = value[20:]
            receivers_dict[file] = raw_scan_data
            i += 1
        else:
            clutter = os.listdir(temp_pdf_dir)
            for file in clutter:
                os.remove(f'{temp_pdf_dir}/{file}')
            exit()

    
    layout = []

    for value in receivers_dict.values():
        for filename in value.values():
            layout.append([sg.Checkbox(filename, default = True, background_color = 'white')])

    window = sg.Window('Scans', resizable = True, icon = parker_icon).Layout([    [sg.Text('Check all of the scans you wish to import.')],
                                                                                    [sg.Column(layout, scrollable=True, background_color = 'white', size = (350,350), expand_x = True, expand_y = True, justification = 'center', key = 'scans_column')],
                                                                                    [sg.Text("Save location:"), sg.Input(default_text = 'F:/Receiving/Receivers', key = 'selected_files'), sg.FolderBrowse(initial_folder = 'F:/Receiving/Receivers')],
                                                                                    [sg.Button('Continue'), sg.Button('Cancel')]    ])
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=='Cancel':
            clutter = os.listdir(temp_pdf_dir)
            for file in clutter:
                os.remove(f'{temp_pdf_dir}/{file}')
            exit()
        elif event == "Continue":
            save_location = values.pop('selected_files')
            del values['Browse']

            page_download_dict = {}
            for filename in receivers_dict.keys():
                page_download_dict[filename] = {}

            for key, value in receivers_dict.items():
                for page, filename in value.items():
                    page_download_dict[key][filename] = [page]

            for key, value in page_download_dict.items():
                for idx, (po_key, page_list) in enumerate(reversed(value.items())):
                    if idx == 0:
                        page_list.append(page_lengths[key]-1)
                        start_page = page_list[0]
                    else:
                        page_list.append(start_page-1)
                        start_page = page_list[0]

            i = 0
            for value in page_download_dict.values():
                for v in value.values():
                    v.append(values[i])
                    i += 1

            window.close()
            pdf_split_page(page_download_dict, len(values), save_location)
```

I haven't included the entire program, as it is almost 400 lines, but I will be happy to if you feel it is needed. The function scan_reader_window() is where it fails every time. Specifically, I know it is somewhere in the first for loop, after sg.one_line_progress_meter, because the progress meter pulls up but the function fails before it completes the first iteration.

Again, this works perfectly as a python file, and as an exe when --noconsole or --onefile are specified. It only fails when I try to do both, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Does anybody have any ideas?
Thank you!

EDIT: It appears to be a poppler issue. I tried running it with --debug, and after it crashes I get the popup message "unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?" I've modified my code so that "poppler_path = 'bin'", and added the bin to my spec file like so:
datas=[('D:/Coding/bin', 'bin')]
but still no luck. Also, because it was requested, here is the log from pyinstaller (sorry, when I copy if from console it strips newlines, not sure how to format better):

D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts>pyinstaller    "receiver_scan_import_wizard.spec" 84 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3 84 INFO:  Python: 3.9.4 84 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 84 INFO:    UPX is not available. 131 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths    ['D:\Work\Receiver Scan Import Wizard',     'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts'] 147    INFO: checking Analysis 147 INFO: Building Analysis because    Analysis-00.toc is non existent 147 INFO: Initializing module    dependency graph... 147 INFO: Caching module graph hooks... 162    WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please   take care they do not conflict. 169 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip   ... 2235 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'. 2235 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib' 4793 INFO:   Caching module dependency graph... 5003 INFO: running Analysis    Analysis-00.toc 5003 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls    to dependent assemblies of final executable   required by    d:\coding\portable_python-3.9.4_x64\app\python\python.exe 5066    WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of  d:\coding\portable_python-3.9.4_x64\app\python\python39.dll 5066    INFO: Analyzing D:\Work\Receiver Scan Import    Wizard\receiver_scan_import_wizard.py 5724 INFO: Processing pre-find   module path hook site from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-site.py'. 5724 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\fake-modules'    7771 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook    setuptools.extern.six.moves from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'. 10513 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-win32com.py'. 10948 INFO: Processing module hooks... 10948 INFO: Loading module    hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'... 11198 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'... 11445 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'... 11498 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'... 11630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 11915 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 11915 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from   'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 11915 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk' 11915 INFO:    Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 11915 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk' 11915 INFO:    Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12100 INFO: checking Tree 12100 INFO: Building Tree because    Tree-00.toc is non existent 12100 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc    12200 INFO: checking Tree 12200 INFO: Building Tree because    Tree-01.toc is non existent 12200 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc    12316 INFO: checking Tree 12316 INFO: Building Tree because    Tree-02.toc is non existent 12316 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc    12332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12417 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12417 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12417 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12448 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12464 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12464 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12517 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py' 12533 INFO:    Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 12533 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13106 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!    13318 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found! 13320  INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13320 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25:    UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is   discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please    use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.  warnings.warn( 13822 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py'    from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from  'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'... 13856 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs 13903 INFO: Analyzing run-time    hooks ... 13919 INFO: Including run-time hook    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py' 13919 INFO: Including run-time hook    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32api.py' 13919 INFO: Including run-time hook    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py' 13919 INFO: Including run-time hook    'D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py' 13919 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries 14462 INFO: Looking for    eggs 14462 INFO: Using Python library    d:\coding\portable_python-3.9.4_x64\app\python\python39.dll 14462    INFO: Found binding redirects: [] 14562 INFO: Warnings written to    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts\build\receiver_scan_import_wizard\warn-receiver_scan_import_wizard.txt 14619 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts\build\receiver_scan_import_wizard\xref-receiver_scan_import_wizard.html 14718 INFO: Appending 'binaries' from .spec 14718 INFO: Appending    'datas' from .spec 14718 INFO: checking PYZ 14718 INFO: Building PYZ   because PYZ-00.toc is non existent 14718 INFO: Building PYZ    (ZlibArchive)    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts\build\receiver_scan_import_wizard\PYZ-00.pyz 14734 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive)    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts\build\receiver_scan_import_wizard\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully. 14772 INFO: checking PKG 14772 INFO: Building  PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent 14772 INFO: Building PKG    (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg 30699 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg   completed successfully. 30795 INFO: Bootloader    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw_d.exe 30796 INFO: checking EXE 30797 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc   is non existent 30797 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc 30977 INFO:   Copying icons from    ['D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\images\icon-windowed.ico'] 30990 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes 30990    INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes 30991 INFO: Writing   RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes 30992 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3    resource with 1384 bytes 30992 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with   38188 bytes 30993 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes    30994 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes 30994 INFO:    Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes 31031 INFO: Updating    manifest in    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts\build\receiver_scan_import_wizard\runw_d.exe.efjmscdq 31040 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0 31211 INFO:    Appending archive to EXE    D:\Coding\Portable_Python-3.9.4_x64\App\Python\Scripts\dist\receiver_scan_import_wizard.exe 37778 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

Comment: What do you mean it fails at some part? did it crush? what exactly happens? and can you add the log you get from pyinstaller?

Comment: What I mean is that it gets to the point where it opens the one_line_progress_meter (key=file_processor), and then before it completes the first iteration, a messagebox pops up with the title "Fatal error detected" which says "Failed to execute script my_script". When I hit ok, the progress meter closes and the program ends prematurely. I'll add the log to my original post right now, as well as updating with some new information I've learned that might help. It appears to be a poppler issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. The issue was with subprocess.Popen(), which is used by the pdf2image module that I utilized. Using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706087/16697889), I was able to modify the file pdf2image.py and now my program works with both --onefile and --noconsole.