# pyinstaller exe doesn't run batch file by using subprocess

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

My GUI program starts some kind of solver (MSC Mentat) which is triggered only with a batch file and I'm using subprocess to trigger it. This batch file takes some arguments and the total command looks like this:

*C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2021.1.0\mentat2021.1\bin\mentat.bat -pr myprocfile.proc -bg -szgr 1124 676*

Here is the snippet from my code:

```py
def start_marc_process(self):
    """Long running task"""

    # Start Process
    try:
        command = "C:\MSC.Software\Marc\2021.1.0\mentat2021.1\bin\mentat.bat -pr myprocfile.proc -bg -szgr 1124 676"
        sb.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=sb.PIPE, stderr=sb.PIPE, stdin=sb.PIPE, cwd=self.working_directory).wait()

    except Exception as ex:
        self.progress.emit("Exception Occured... Ready.")
        self.finished_wexception.emit()

    else:
        # Emit signal when long running task finished.
        self.finished_normally.emit()
```

I can run this code from my vscode integrated terminal and it works perfectly. But when I created an executable by using pyinstaller, it doesn't execute the subprocess line regardless of using --noconsole argument on pyinstaller.

There is a similar question here: [subprocess seems not working in pyinstaller exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463238/subprocess-seems-not-working-in-pyinstaller-exe-file) . But in my case, the subprocess command is not an exe file but batch file. I tried my code with dummy subprocess commands like "notepad.exe" or "echo hello" and it totally works fine on either integrated terminal and exe file with and without --noconsole argument on pyinstaller.

I also tried `os.system()`, `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.run()` and same thing happened again and again.

By the way, I'm using Pyqt5 and Pyqt threading to prevent the "not responding" window because of long process.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Batch files need a shell (e.g. cmd.exe) to run them.

Comment: @balmy, but isn't that what `shell=True` does?

Comment: try running your batch as cmd /C "battchfile.bat param1 param2 etc"

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @balmy. I tried cmd.exe /C and cmd.exe prefixes but it didn't work. I also tried it on simple hello.bat file which includes echo hello command to be sure that the batch file doesn't cause the problem. With this way it didn't executed subprocess line on either vscode or pyinstaller .exe file. I also tried these prefixes with and without shell=true flag combinations and the results was the same.

Comment: Your `command` string doesn't have the contents you think, due to escape character handling - specifically, `\202` is being interpreted as a non-ASCII character, and `\b` is being interpreted as a backspace.  I don't see how this could have worked under any circumstances at all.  You either need to put an `r` in front to make it a raw string literal, or double all the backslashes.