# 'OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid' in PySimpleGUI while using '-w' in Pyinstaller, Speech Recognition and Pyttsx3

Tags: python, user-interface, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

So I created a program with PySimpleGUI and then made .exe file from it with Pyinstaller. Here is my command:

`pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.dummy --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.espeak --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.nsss --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5 -F -w -i "C:\Users\icons\logo.ico" prog.py`
-F for one file prog
-w for windowed app (without command prompt)
-i for icon
By the way when I make it without '-w' it works perfectly, but I want app with no cmd
My code:

```
layout = [
    [sg.Text('', size=(30, 2)), sg.Text('Press "Start" button', size=(55, 12), key='-MAIN-')],
    [sg.Button('Start', size=(10,2)), sg.Button('Info', size=(10,2))],
]
window = sg.Window('App', layout, size=(800, 500))
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Start':
        def threading_main_process(seconds):
            window['-MAIN-'].update("Starting...")

            engine = pyttsx3.init()
            engine.say("Hello!")
            engine.runAndWait()
            def search_files_thread(seconds):
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
                    for file in files:
                        if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            threading.Thread(target = search_files_thread, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()
            while True:
                    r = sr.Recognizer()
                    window['-MAIN-'].update('Say Hello')
                    with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        audio = r.listen(source)
                        said = ''

                        try:
                            said = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN")
                            def threading_said(seconds):
                                time.sleep(10)
                                window['-MAIN-'].update('')
                            threading.Thread(target = threading_said, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()
                        except Exception as exception:
                            window['-MAIN-'].update(exception)

                        if said == 'hello':
                            engine.say("Hi, how are you")
                            engine.runAndWait()
                            def threading_print(seconds):
                                time.sleep(1)
                                window['-MAIN-'].update("Hi, how are you")
                                time.sleep(10)
                                window['-MAIN-'].update('')
                            threading.Thread(target = threading_print, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()
        threading.Thread(target = threading_main_process, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()
    if event == 'Info':
        window['-MAIN-'].update('Press start button and say hello')
        def threading_info(seconds):
            time.sleep(10)
            window['-MAIN-'].update('')
        threading.Thread(target = threading_info, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()
            
window.close()
```

and I get error:

```
'OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid'
```