# Errors with pyinstaller after compiling

Tags: python, pyinstaller

### Heading

Hello!
Have python code what should call shell! When i use it as python code on windows all works fine!
After compiling it with pyinstaller I am getting Windows 6 error Handler is invalid
Here is piece of code

```
def shell(self, task_id, command):
        import subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     cwd=self.current_directory)
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        out = stderr if stderr else stdout
        return out.decode()
```

Comment: can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: shell cmd.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Excel.exe
[WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593348/winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid-from-python-check-output-spawn-in-electron-app

Comment: So I should set values of stdout and stderr to DEVNULL, instead PIPE